# Как сделать редактируемое меню в spa (yii2 + vue)?

Tags: yii2, vue.js, меню, spa

Делаю spa админку (yii2 + vue) с возможностью редактирования многоуровневого меню. Предполагается добавление, удаление и редактирование элементов меню. Нет общей картины реализации. Подскажите пожалуйста в общих чертах, буду очень благодарен

Comment: По какому-либо триггеру, заменять соответствующий пункт меню с `span` на `input` и наоборот